# Retrieving m3u8 links for testing AWS streaming/subtitles

Tags: amazon-web-services, twitch, youtube-livestreaming-api, aws-elemental

I'm not sure if here is the best place for asking, but let me try.

I've created a stack on AWS for live streaming with subtitles, based on this template: https://github.com/awslabs/live-streaming-with-automated-multi-language-subtitling

To be able to test it I need a valid m3u8 url as input.

So I started looking around to find an easy way to broadcast myself and get a m3u8 link, Twitch appeared to be the simplest way to get it.

Cool, but how do I get the m3u8 link?
After searching a bit I found a [python script](https://gist.github.com/baderj/8593472)

Tried it...and failed, reading the comments I found a way to change the code and make it work... apparently

Cool, now I got my url

Added it to AWS, didn't work, this [player](https://videojs.github.io/http-streaming/) failed to load with an error message: **The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.**

After some attempts, restarting channels and so... somehow it started working, cool, maybe I just had to wait a bit? No idea how it started working.

Ok, tested a bit and it was working nicely, apart from a bit of lag
So, I decided to create another CloudFormation stack, now including CloudFront.

Did the same proceedings, and kept the working one as a fallback

But can't make it work again, in any of these

I re-ran the script to get the new twtich link, didn't work
I have tried to get any live streaming from youtube and extract it using **youtube-dl**

Got a certificate error: ERROR: Unable to download webpage:  (caused by URLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:841)'),))

Tried a python utility called [livestramer](http://docs.livestreamer.io/plugin_matrix.html)
Got another error: **Unable to open URL: https://api.twitch.tv/api/channels/mychannel/access_token.json (400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://api.twitch.tv/api/channels/mychannel/access_token.json?as3=t)**

Tried a bunch of solutions, adding client-id header, didn't work

Anyway, the former script seems to work and give me a m3u8 link, but it doesn't work at all now

Adding the no-cloudfront link, it seems that it is loaded, but I only get a black screen.
The Cloudfront one fails even to load, giving the same error as before

Does anyone know how to fix it? Or maybe another website that I can easily broadcast myself and retrieve the m3u8 urls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'have used [streamlink](https://github.com/streamlink/streamlink/) instead and it works like charm

How to use to retrieve the m3u8 url:

```
streamlink --stream-url https://www.twitch.tv/username best
```